# I think my bootloader is not loading my Window 7 but boot my grub

Tags: grub2, windows

Below is my boot-repair info :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1403448/

it could load ubuntu in the grub loader but not the window.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your not able to see your grub menu then press hold shift while booting to manual invoke the bootmenu and select Windows
2. If your able to see the boot menu but cant find windows on it then try executing `update-grub` from the terminal in Ubuntu.That should update the grub menu.